# Print factorial of given input -1

Tags: python-3.x

I try to print number of combinations of given count of elements. - Yes, there was such topic, but I'm very beginner of Python and I want to understand my errors. Count is true just for *x=4*. And one more question: why in the end it prints "None"?

```
x=int(input('Count of elements for combinations: '))
a=x
from math import factorial
def everywithevery(x):
    y=x
    print ('Graphical representation:')
    print (x*'_ ')
    while x>0:
        print ((x-1)*'* ')
        x=x-1
    print('Stars count is equal combinations count. Total count is: ',factorial((y-1)));

print(everywithevery(a));
```

There you can try my script: http://goo.gl/EDFkYM

Comment: Does this code work? If so it's probably a better fit for codereview.SE. If not, you need to add your given input and output as well as the EXPECTED output.

Comment: It works and stars are printed properly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for review of working code. Recommend migration to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AdamSmith: Nowhere does this user ask for a review of working code.  From the explanation alone, it appears to be off-topic on Code Review.  Please be aware of our [Help Center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Jamal My first comment is asking if this is working code, to which the OP responds "it works and stars are printed properly." From your help center (which you have helpfully linked), this question follows all the bulletpoints you have listed for "I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?"

Comment: @AdamSmith: I must've just looked at the question, which wasn't updated.  Anyway, the OP has already deleted the CR question.  Cross-posting can be a pain sometimes, though flagging for migration is still preferred until CR fully graduates.

Comment: @Jamal agreed! Frankly the question as-asked wasn't a good fit for anywhere, but when OP said that it's working code that he's trying to improve I figured CR may have been a better fit. I tend to be overeager to migrate bad questions rather than simply VTC though -- I'd rather see a coder in need get some help rather than just be sent away.

Comment: Only stars printing is working properly, maybe I used wrong math function in 12 line... anyway thanks for help @Aerofil-Kite

Comment: @AdamSmith: Regarding migration, flagging is best (now you know).  Cross-posting can bring about this confusion, and still causes some problems for us.  Anyway, this isn't the place to discuss this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You print the following line but you didn't return any thing from everywithevery function. Thats why that line prints none

```
print(everywithevery(a));
```

Just use

```
everywithevery(a)
```